# Can I get a String directly from split?

Tags: string, rust

This code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = String::from("The quick brown fox");

    for s in input.split(" ") {
        let s2: String = s;
        println!("{:?}", s2)
    }
}
```

gives me this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\main.rs:8:26
  |
8 |         let s2: String = s;
  |                 ------   ^
  |                 |        |
  |                 |        expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&str`
  |                 |        help: try using a conversion method: `s.to_string()`
  |                 expected due to this
```

Do I have to do what the compiler recommends (converting `s` inside the loop) or can I change the loop so that I get `String`s from the splitting directly?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae330f959358a0ae2460dbd1f52c2cee

Comment: @Stargateur The question you linked doesn't really help because I know how to convert it, but I wanted to know if I can do it inside the loop header. Your Playground link on the other hand seems to be the answer to my question. :)

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry, which rule are you referring to? Include the `fn main()` to make it a MWE? I will do that next time, my apologies.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html#implementations, please check the `Iterator` implementation it always yields `&str`, it is better if you specify why you need this done internally ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden Just learning about the capabilities of Rust. Because the left side of `in` is some kind of pattern I'm not really clear yet on what is possible there.

Comment: Yes it is a pattern, you can see it from the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops), also you can do something like this : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3eea90662f106c2273a842d4aea29e93, (edit:I haven't seen it is done by @Stargateur before, it is just same)